# Solving a quadratic program with simple linear constraints

Tags: optimization, positive-definite, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

This is related to an attempt at solving this problem : [Best rank-$1$ approximation of matrix with condition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648133/best-rank-1-approximation-of-matrix-with-condition)

Let $M\in\mathbb R^{m\times m}$ be PSD symmetric and $a\in \mathbb R^m$ be such that $0\leq a$, i.e. for $i=1,\dots, m$, $a_i\geq 0$. I am trying to solve the following problem :
\begin{align*}
&\min_{\substack{b\in\mathbb R^m:\\0\leq b}} ~(a+b)^TM(a+b)
\end{align*}

Since the problem is convex, the KKT conditions are both necessary and sufficient and are ($\mu$ are the Lagrange multipliers)
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
2M(a+b) = \mu\\
0\leq b\\
0\leq \mu\\
\mu^T b=0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

> Is there any closed form for this problem ? or a fast and simple algorithm that optimize it ?

Comment: By solving the problem, you mean minimize the function $(a+b)^T M (a+b)$? At first sight I thought it was about solving the first equation.

Comment: @CarlosAdir Yes, the first equality is trivial, the optimization is not.

Comment: @P.Quinton So, you know it is a convex problem which can be solved by some solvers such as CVX?

Comment: @RiverLi yes I know some solvers that can do that, including scipy.optimize. Those are however too slow on this problem, and I am trying to get a grasp at what kind of steps they propose. The original problem was some biconvex optimization and therefore just a good step for this problem is already good progress.

Comment: Just curious: how large is $m$?

Comment: $M = Q\Lambda Q^T$; $b_i = \max {-[Q(Q^Ta)]_i, 0}$?

Comment: @fedja $m$ is rather small, around $32$, the problem is that I launch this program a crasy amount of time on `pytorch` and therefore I would like to make it as simple as possible to not have to send data back and forth from GPU to CPU to another program etc...

Comment: @rumathe Yes I tried something like that, but I think it is hard to show that $\mu = 2 M(a+b)$ is positive right ? If it is the case, then it is very nice. Also I think that $QQ^T=I$ right ? so it cannot be exactly that.

Comment: @P.Quinton I tried to share a few thoughts about your main question in the linked thread. Let me know what you think of them. With $m$ as small as 32 I can even try to run some examples to see whether my proposed alternative approach is reasonably efficient.